# Not able to start ballerina as gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ballerina

I've downloaded the WSO2-ApiManager-3.0.0-m29 release and I'm trying to invoke an api via the ballerina gateway. When I'm trying to start ballerina with:

```
bin/ballerina run service services.bsz
```

It gives me the following error:

> interceptor deployment directory
>   D:Developments/wso2apim-gateway-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT bin../handler  doesn’t
>   exist for server connector ballerina.net.http .

I am new to ballerina. How do I start the ballerina gateway?

Answer (score 1):

From m27 onward,  the old gateway is not supported. It now uses the latest micro gateway v3. Download it from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-microgateway/releases/tag/v3.0.0-m2) . The documentation on how to invoke an api using micro gateway can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM300/Microgateway+Quick+Start).